# SQL Group By Having Where Statements

Tags: sql, ms-access, group-by, aggregate-functions

I have a `MS Access` table tracking quantities of products at end month as below. 
I need to generate the latest quantity for a specified ProductId at a specified date e.g.
The Quantity for `ProductId 1 on 15-Feb-12 is 100`, The Quantity for `ProductId 1 on 15-Mar-12 is 150`.

```
ProductId | ReportingDate | Quantity|  
1         | 31-Jan-12     | 100     |  
2         | 31-Jan-12     | 200     |  
1         | 28-Feb-12     | 150     |  
2         | 28-Feb-12     | 250     |  
1         | 31-Mar-12     | 180     |  
2         | 31-Mar-12     | 280     |
```

My SQL statement below bring all previous values instead the latest one only. Could anyone assist me troubleshoot the query.

```
SELECT Sheet1.ProductId, Max(Sheet1.ReportingDate) AS MaxOfReportingDate, Sheet1.Quantity
FROM Sheet1
GROUP BY Sheet1.ProductId, Sheet1.Quantity, Sheet1.ReportingDate, Sheet1.ProductId
HAVING (((Sheet1.ReportingDate)<#3/15/2012#) AND ((Sheet1.ProductId)=1))
```

Comment: If you are selecting single product, you can use order by and select Top 1.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's @naveen's idea:

```
SELECT TOP 1 Sheet1.ProductId, Sheet1.ReportingDate AS MaxOfReportingDate, Sheet1.Quantity
FROM Sheet1
WHERE (Sheet1.ProductId = 1)
AND (Sheet1.ReportingDate < #2012/03/15#)
ORDER BY Sheet1.ReportingDate DESC
```

Although note that MsAccess selects top with ties, so this won't work if you have more than one row per `ReportingDate`, `ProductId` combo. (But at the same time, this means that the data isn't deterministic anyway)

*Edit* - I meant that if you have a contradiction in your data like below, you'll get 2 rows back.

```
ProductId | ReportingDate | Quantity|  
1         | 31-Jan-12     | 100    
1         | 31-Jan-12     | 200
```

Comment: Thank you, the code has worked perfectly. Though I have no clue what you mean in your comment...

Comment: I have understood. The data has only 1 ProdId Date combo for any pair, but it is something I will be on the lookout for. Many thanks @StuartLC