# SQL Group By Statement, Max Values For Grouped Data

Tags: sql, ms-access, group-by, aggregate-functions

My question is similar to this question [SQL Group By Having Where Statements](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21402298/2849004) , the only difference is I need to generate the latest quantities for all the ProductIds at a specified date e.g.
The Quantity for `ProductId 1 on 15-Feb-12 is 100` &  `ProductId 2 on 15-Feb-12 is 200`,The Quantity for `ProductId 1 on 15-Mar-12 is 150` & `ProductId 2 on 15-Mar-12 is 250`. from a `MS Access` table tracking quantities of products at end month as below.

```
ProductId | ReportingDate | Quantity|  
1         | 31-Jan-12     | 100     |  
2         | 31-Jan-12     | 200     |  
1         | 28-Feb-12     | 150     |  
2         | 28-Feb-12     | 250     |  
1         | 31-Mar-12     | 180     |  
2         | 31-Mar-12     | 280     |
```

My desired output on **March 15 2012** should be a query as below:

```
ProductId | ReportingDate | Quantity|  
1         | 28-Feb-12     | 150     |  
2         | 28-Feb-12     | 250     |
```

My current SQL statement below returns the result of only one ProductID. Could anyone assist me expand the query to show all ProductIds?

```
SELECT TOP 1 Sheet1.ProductId, Sheet1.ReportingDate AS MaxOfReportingDate, Sheet1.Quantity
FROM Sheet1
WHERE (Sheet1.ProductId = 1)
AND (Sheet1.ReportingDate < #2012/03/15#)
ORDER BY Sheet1.ReportingDate DESC
```

Comment: You are selecting `top 1` and `WHERE (Sheet1.ProductId = 1)` - that would be why you are getting only one row. Have you tried adding a `group by`?

Comment: @Blorgbeard I cant seem to place the group by clause properly, I have edited my question to show that this is where I am.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to join with a sub-query that lists the latest date up to the desired date:

```
SELECT
Sheet1.ProductId, Sheet1.ReportingDate, Sheet1.Quantity
FROM Sheet1 INNER JOIN
(SELECT Sheet1.ProductId, MAX(Sheet1.ReportingDate) AS MaxOfReportingDate
FROM Sheet1
WHERE ReportingDate < #2012/03/15#
GROUP BY ProductId) AS a 
ON Sheet1.ProductId = a.ProductId AND Sheet1.ReportingDate = a.MaxOfReportingDate
ORDER BY Sheet1.ReportingDate DESC
```